# Redirecting from www to no www in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, redirect, django, 301-redirect

I'm developing a Django app with nginx reverse proxy and gunicorn application server. Being a newbie web developer, I need help with redirecting `www` traffic to `no www` at the webserver level. I'm currently doing the same at the middleware level inside the app, but need to improve performance.

Currently my nginx virtual host file is laid out as follows:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=100m inactive=6m;

upstream my_server {
    server unix:/home/myuser/myproject/myfolder/myproject.sock  fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # a bunch of 'location' blocks e.g. 'location /' or 'location @http_proxy_to_app', etc. 

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # SSL related stuff

    # a bunch of 'location' blocks e.g. 'location /' or 'location @http_proxy_to_app', etc.

}
```

How would I redirect **www to no-www** in this scenario? Most of the examples I've seen explain that I need to add one more dedicated `server` block at the top like so:

```
server {
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Other suggestions have been to include something like the following inside my server blocks (inside `location /`). I'm unsure whether this would be compatible with reverse proxy related code:

```
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)$) {
    rewrite / $scheme://$1 permanent;
}
```

Being a newbie, I wanted to confirm which practice to use (and why) given how my nginx file is currently laid out, hence this question.

---

Here's what my actual config looks like:

```
server {

server_name example.com;
listen 443 ssl;

#ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myserver.key;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
#ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5; 
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1250m;
ssl_session_timeout 180m;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
#ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/COMODO_DV_SHA-2_under_SHA-2root.crt;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.ca-bundle;

# write error log file for https errors:
error_log /var/log/nginx/https-error_log warn;

location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ { root /home/myuser/myproj/myapp; expires 24h; add_header Vary Accept-Encoding; access_log off; }

.... more config to follow ...

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred setup for a web server handling http://example.com, https://example.com, http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com is the following when the `example.com` domain and https are preferred:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    listen 80;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ... actual server configuration ...
}
```

In this setup, there is only one actual URL `https://example.com` for reaching the site content, which is good for indexing. In your current setup, the same site content is available with all URLs, which causes duplicate issues with Google.

Defining a separate virtual host for the redirects is the preferred way, because evaluating the `if` statement causes duplicate work for requests already coming in to the correct virtual host block.

Comment: Question: my actual server config is currently two server blocks, one with `listen 80` and another with `listen 443 ssl;`. If I were to keep that constant while first only introducing redirection in my set up, would I simply add the top two server blocks you've written in your answer. Yes I know it makes `listen 80` redundant once it's functioning correctly, but I just want to do it one step at a time without breaking anything. I hope you get what I'm asking.

Comment: You should make an identical testing environment for your changes and verify configuration in that before making changes to the production environment. And no, you cannot simply add those two blocks to your configuration, because then you would have two definitions for `example.com:80`, `www.example.com:80` and `example.com:443`. There can be only one configuration for each domain:port pair.

Comment: Actually the correct term here is FQDN, Fully Qualified Domain name. Those must be separate. Second block FQDN is `www.example.com` and third block FQDN is `example.com`.

Comment: Another follow up question: when I try this solution, it doesn't work and nginx's error log shows me `*922862344 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 69.171.225.149, server: 0.0.0.0:443`. Do note that in my original nginx set up, SSL works perfectly.

Comment: I didn't include the certificate configuration lines in the example, you need to include `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives in the SSL blocks.

Comment: Yep, but if you check out the config I just added at the end of my question, you'll see my final server block does contain all the relevant SSL config. This thing works when I have separate 80 and 443 blocks. But as soon as I redirect everything to 443 as per your advice, it fails.

Comment: And you had those directives in all `server` blocks with SSL?

Comment: No, not where I do `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;`. Should I include all the directives till `ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.ca-bundle;` in that server block too? I thought it's only job was redirection to the *correct* server block (which then contained all the required SSL config).

Comment: You need the certificate configuration in every `server` block where you have `listen 443 ssl;`.

Comment: Gotcha. One last thing: would those other server blocks also need the SSL stapling config?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to have those in them.